# How can I setup PHP Redirects after Login?

Tags: php, sql, database

New to PHP Here, trying to figure out a couple of things. When users log into the system, I would like for the PHP to look at the Group ID and then run through a system of checks to find a match. Once the Group ID is matched, it will then redirect users to the appropriate webpage. How would I go about doing this with this piece of code?

These are the columns in my table:

```
Name, Email, Password, Group
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Looking forward to learning something new!

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbName");
//"localhost", "userName" is username; "Password" is password; "dbName" is DB_Name;
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_reg WHERE UserName='$_POST[UserName]' && Password='$_POST[Password]'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($count==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $_POST['UserName'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];
    header("location: redirect.html");
    }
else
{
    echo "Invalid username or password";
    }   

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Try to use `header("Location: index.php");`

Comment: Try using an IF or maybe a SWITCH

Comment: **Are we supposed to guess** where Group ID can be found in your system??

Comment: Looking more and more like a **D.I.F.M** question

Comment: GroupID is actually one of the fields in a table that we created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely as an example use this:

```
<?php
    /*
        GroupID 1 = Standard User
        GroupID 2 = Special User
        GroupID 3 = Power User

    */

    $GroupID = $_POST['GroupID']; // Assume 1 


    switch($GroupID){
        case 1: 
        // If GroupID = 1 Redirect to correct page
            header("Location: StandardPage.html");
        case 2:
        // If GroupID = 2 Redirect to correct page
            header("Location: SpecialUser.html");
        case 3:
        // If GroupID = 3 Redirect to correct page
            header("Location: Poweruser.html");
        default:
        // If GroupID does not match set user groups redirect to error page
            header("Location: Error.php");
    }


?>
```

Assume this as a cleaner `if` statement. Please Consult the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and learn how to adapt this to your exact needs

as the lack of information in your question, I will not be more precise. This is a step in the right direction, but all this is of guess work. Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for this! I honestly believe that this will suit my needs right here.  Could I place it under the end marking of the initial PHP statement or embed it within?

Comment: @B.James Please note, that this snippet isn't exactly done to fit your current code. You would need to adapt this to suit your environment. This would be best suited to add after you have validated your user and added the correct information to the session, once you've pulled your user group for the specific user. You would change `$GroupID` to the valid you'd get from your databse.   In this example, Error.php would only be called if the user has been validated, but the user does not contain a group of either 1,2 or 3.. Be it they have Group = 0, or Group = 4. It would trigger the error

Comment: If this has helped and solved your problem, please press the green tick under where the votes are to mark this as an answer for other users who might browse to this question looking for help